# Batch How to convert formula using a user input variable

Tags: math, batch-file, input, command, output

G'day folks,

Hoping to find some help here.  I've searched tirelessly but to no avail.
I have here a code that I ask for user input and saving that to a variable.

I need to turn that variable as a variable as part of a mathematical equation.
I will also need to output the result on the screen..

Here is what I have thus far.

```
@Echo off

:Start

Set /p weight=What is the Current Weight of Unit?
If %weight% LEQ 17 goto convert

:convert

set /a var=%var% 15*2333
set /a var=%var%/7

Echo Total US Gallons in Unit: %var%
```

Thanks in advance.

I have edited the code to better reflect my program.
but all I am getting is the **15*2333 = 4999**

I am asking for users to type in a range of numbers from 17-0 and saving that as 
a variable **(%weight%)**

This works..as it should

I now need the program to take **%weight%** and do this equation **15*2333**

Next  I need the result of **%weight% (After 15*2333) then divide that by 7**.
After all of this I need the program to output on screen the result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you edit your post to properly format the code you have. Simply mark it and click on the button with the curly braces above the edit area. That will indent the code by four spaces, which in Markdown renders as preformatted text. It would also be nice if you could point out in what way your current efforts are not enough, i.e. where this approach fails.

Comment: 1. `goto convert`?? Where is it? 2. `set /a var=%var% 15*2333`?? What should that do?

Comment: 3. `%var%`, not `%weight%`?

Comment: Assuming that you mean to do `set /a var=%weight% 15*2333` - It will not be a valid operation. If for example, the user enters 20, that line will evaluate to `set /a var=20 15*2333` - you're missing an operator.

Comment: I have edited my original post, I hope I've properly formatted the post.

Answer (score 1):

how is this:

```
@Echo off

:Start

Set /p weight=What is the Current Weight of Unit?
If %weight% LEQ 17 goto convert

:Start1
:convert
cls
set /a var=weight
set /a var=var+15*2333
set /a var=var/7
Echo Total US Gallons in Unit: %var%
```

or, my revised version:

```
@echo off
set/pz=What is the Current Weight of Unit?
if %z% GTR 17 exit /b
cls
set /a z=(z+15*2333)/7
echo Total US Gallons in Unit: %z%
```

replace + with the missing operator

Answer (score 1):

you need to rename start1 to convert, replace weight with var, and add in the missing operand.
:)

Comment: ummmm, it looks like you just sumed up comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help nephi12.  I tried what you suggested.  Works good, but I am still getting 4999 as a result.  Looks like it's still not using the variable the user inputs.  Also, I am a bit confused on missing operator.  I've tried searching, haven't really found a good explanation of what or how to fix this.

Comment: take a deep look to your `set /a var=%var% 15*2333`. Imagine, user had inputted "12". So your equation is: `set /a var=12 15*2333` That will never work. There is an operator missing between `12` and `15` (between `%var%` and `12*2333`. Nephi choosed a `+` to show you the problem.

Comment: I have figured it out, thank you everyone for the help.  Here is what I came up with..

:convert
cls
Set /p weight=What is the Current Weight of Unit?
If %weight% LEQ 17 goto convertge1
cls
:convertge1
set /a var=weight
set /a var=var*2059
set /a var=var/7
Echo Total US Gallons in Unit: %var%